# Reading Between Specific Lines in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file of the following format:

```
...text
LINE A
text
text
text
LINE B
text...
```

What I am trying to do is only work with the text between LINE A and LINE B.

Essentially, I'm trying the following format:

```
for line in text_file:
     if line.startswith("LINE A"):
          Do something until LINE B
```

I don't care about what line number it is on because LINE A can be arbitrarily placed in the text file, and the text between LINE A and LINE B is of variable length.

Any tips or pointers would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea. You can just add while not line.startswith("LINE B"): to the inner loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a state machine. In this case I use the states `reading` and `not reading`. Since there are only two states I can use one boolean to switch the states.

```
reading=False
for line in text_file:
    if line.startswith("LINE A"):
        reading=True
    elif line.startswith("LINE B"):
        reading=False
    elif reading:
        Do something
```

Comment: May as well add `break` in case 2 if you do it this way. No need to keep looping till line 100 if "LINE B" is on line 5. :)

Comment: This is clever! I haven't tried it yet, but I think this will work great for my purposes. Thanks! I'll update you when I give it a shot. And @Two-BitAlchemist, excellent point! Thanks!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: That's true unless you want to capture multiple blocks.

Comment: @codycrossley: If you like the answer please upvote and accept it.

Comment: @Dakkaron, I was waiting to try it out first. I just did, and it worked great! Thank you so much! I will accept the answer as soon as it permits (3 minutes from now until I can accept it)

Comment: @codycrossley: Thanks a lot ;)